move_group pick() function computes weird movements
I'm recently getting into ROS (Melodic, Ubuntu 18.04) and MoveIt!.
For my project, I need to grasp an object from the table where the robot (a franka eremika panda) is placed. I wrote a python script following more or less the idea of the pick and place tutorial provided here.
However, I want the arm to follow a cartesian path and then grasp the object. I use the compute_cartesian_path of the move_group and so far so good.
I then initialize the Grasp(), and I set the grasp pose to the current one (where the arm is after having followed the path) and pre_grasp_approach and post_grasp_retreat are as it follows:
    grasps.pre_grasp_approach.direction.header.frame_id = "panda_link0"
    grasps.pre_grasp_approach.direction.vector.x = 0.0
    grasps.pre_grasp_approach.direction.vector.y = 0.0
    grasps.pre_grasp_approach.direction.vector.z = 1
    grasps.pre_grasp_approach.min_distance = 0.0
    grasps.pre_grasp_approach.desired_distance = 0.01

    grasps.post_grasp_retreat.direction.header.frame_id = "panda_link0"
    grasps.post_grasp_retreat.direction.vector.x = 0.0
    grasps.post_grasp_retreat.direction.vector.x = 0.0
    grasps.post_grasp_retreat.direction.vector.z = 1
    grasps.post_grasp_retreat.min_distance = 0.0
    grasps.post_grasp_retreat.desired_distance = 0.01  

Then, I call the move_group.pick() function with the created grasp pose.
For whatever reason, despite the object being literally in-between the grasps, the pick function still rotates the joints in weird ways (which also are different each execution), before returning the end-effector to the pose I initially brought it to.
I was wondering if there is any way to stop the pick function from doing weird movements, and if that's not possible, if there is a way to directly communicate with the panda_fingers and close them.
